TV show about a guy who can see a couple of minutes into the future
I saw this once on TV. It was a trailer from some TV show. It was on AXN in my country (Serbia) 3-4 years ago. I looked at the TV for 2-3 seconds.
As far as I could understand, there's a guy who can see in future - 10-20 sec, or couple minutes, I'm not sure how far into future. I think he was a detective. All I could see is that guy having a flash about someone killing him, then he hid behind church benches. 
It's not the movie Next or the show FlashForward.

Hi. Do you know how old this show was? Where it aired? What the guy looked like? And do you remember anything else about it (plot points, scenes, other characters etc.)?

To less to go forward

No.I was asleep,when i turned on the other side,i looked at tv for 2-3 sec,all i could see is,that guy having a flash about someone killing him,then he hid behind church benches,that was all

And you don't remember when you saw it (Last year? 20 years ago?), and in which country? Sorry if I sound bothersome, but please realize that these extra details 1. Help us out, and 2. Improve the question and make it less likely to be closed.

Sorry,but whatever i type,someone removes half of my words...It was on AXN in my country,3-4 years ago.Serbia

You could check out IMDB keywords search and http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=vision-of-the-future

This sounds like The Dead Zone

But Johnny himself is also not the same person he once was: he now finds himself in possession of amazing psychic powers which allow him to see into the lives of anyone he touches.

For the brief snippet that you saw it might look like he can see the near future, indeed, quite often he does see what a person is going to do ...
This has also been made as a film.
